# How to see the comment on shelvesets in MSVS2013?

Tags: visual-studio

MSVS2010 allowed to see the shelveset's comment by viewing a shelveset's details.  In MSVS2013, I can't seem to find it.

Does anyone know how to display a shelveset's comment under MSVS2013?

This is what it looked like under MSVS 2010:

[image: Unshelve]

Note the comment column.  Going to details shows this:

[image: Shelveset Details]

Note the Comment box.  Both are populated with the comments used when the shelveset was created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still in the Shelveset Details in the Team Explorer tab, under "Comment", it just looks like a blank text box if there is no comment.

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181403.aspx#view

[image]

Comment: All of the shelvesets I shelved in the past had comments.  There is nothing there now.  If I go back to MSVS2010, I see the comments.

Comment: When I say there's nothing there now, I mean that the dialogue you pictured doesn't show the comment in use for the shelveset selected.

Comment: @Adrian then can you post a screenshot of the shelveset details page?

Comment: @EdwardThomson Yeah, I was just doing that.  However, even the Unshelve window shows at least part of the comment.

Comment: Wait, I think I may be looking at the wrong window.  How did you get that `Team Explorer - Shelveset Details` window up?  I got my windows originally from the `Pending Changes` window.

Comment: @Adrian I meant a screenshot of what you see in the VS2013 Team Explorer Page.  If you're looking at the Find Shelvesets page, then double-click on a single shelveset to view the Shelveset Details page.

Comment: @EdwardThomson, this interface is significantly different that I'm still finding my way around.  I just found the Find Shelveset page and that contains what I want.  Thanks!

Comment: @Adrian Sorry, I was afk, glad you found it.  You are right about the UI differences, especially if you skipped VS2012 ;)